# python2 select link using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I select the link "https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/e1" using beautifulsoup in python?

```
<a ng-href="https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/e1" ng-bind-
html="toTrust(article._data.title)" class="ng-binding" 
href="https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/e1">A Perioperative eHealth Program to 
Enhance Postoperative Recovery After Abdominal Surgery: Process Evaluation of 
a Randomized Controlled Trial</a>
```

I have tried the following code but it returns without the above link I want.

```
for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print i["href"]
```

Comment: What parser engine did you use?

Comment: I use requests library to get the website

Comment: Your code works for me on Python 3, what is the original link you parsed the HTML snippet from?

Comment: The original link I phrased was https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/

Comment: @O.Suleiman the original link I phrased was https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/

Comment: @ChristopherChu Your code works on myside with python2.7 & beautifulsoup4==4.6.0

Comment: @ChristopherChu I think you need to give the original url for your requests library call, as we cannot reproduce your problem, maybe some encoding issue for original web?

Comment: @atline  the original url is https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/

Comment: @ChristopherChu Really strange, I manually open this page and search the page source code, and cannot find `https://www.jmir.org/2018/1/e1` in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name of the class:

```
soup.find('a',{'class':'ng-binding'})['href']
```